# ASP.NET Core Razer Pages Not posting Error message on client-side-server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pick up the error messages on the client-server-side but nothing is throwing the error when the form is submitted with blank text boxes. I'm using `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Shipper")]` on the backend. I have done this on another page and it works but not on this one for some reason. Any suggestions?

```
<h2>Add Supplier</h2>
<br />

<div class="border container" style="padding:30px">

    <form method="post">

        @*Supplier*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Supplier"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Supplier" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        @*PointOfContact*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="PointOfContact"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PointOfContact" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        @*Address*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Address"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        @*City*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="City"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        @*State*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="State"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        @*ZipCode*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="ZipCode"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        @*Phone*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Phone"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        @*EmailAddress*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="EmailAddress"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        @*Save & Cancel Buttons*@
        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-3 offset-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-danger form-control" />
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>

@section Scripts{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Here is my code from the code behind with all the property variables.

```
public class SupplierAddModel : PageModel
{

        //Supplier
        [Display(Name = "Supplier")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Supplier.")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Supplier { get; set; }

        //PointOfContact
        [Display(Name = "Point Of Contact")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Point Of Contact.")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string PointOfContact { get; set; }

        //Address
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an Address.")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        //City
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a City.")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        //State
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a State.")]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string State { get; set; }

        //ZipCode
        [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Zip Code.")]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        //Phone
        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Phone.")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        //EmailAddress
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an Email Address.")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any input field with name `Shipper` in your form! Add your form model to the question please.

Comment: I have added more information.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I forgot to use the asp-for on the inputs.

Comment: @Yes it is. that was the issue

Answer (score 1):

Your input fields does not contain the `asp-for` tag helper. Make your input fields as follows:

```
<input asp-for="Supplier" class="form-control" />
```